# Looping through an array of object based on ID in ngrx effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to loop through the ids, present in the array of objects and then pass it to another action. I tried data.foreach and I get an error. Most probably I am not using the correct RXjs operator. Any help in this would be highly appreciated.

Example data= [{id:1, name: 'name1'}, {id:2, name: 'name1'}]

```
loadSucces$ = createEffect(() =>
            this.actions$.pipe(
                ofType(Actions.loadSuccess),
                switchMap(([data]) =>
// data returns an array of objects, from whose id I want to go through
                    this.service
                        .get('data.id')
                        .pipe(
                            map(serviceData =>
                                Actions.loadDataSuccess({ serviceData })
                            ),
                            catchError(error =>
                                of(Actions.loadDataSuccess({ error }))
                            )
                        )



                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: You can try looking into `forkJoin` or `combineLatest`. https://medium.com/upstate-interactive/combining-multiple-api-calls-into-an-ngrx-effect-9211adfc6535

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://timdeschryver.dev/snippets/multiple-service-calls-from-an-effect

```
refresh$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CustomerActions.refresh),
    exhaustMap(({ customerIds }) =>
      merge(
        ...ids.map(id =>
          this.customersService.getCustomer(id).pipe(
            map(CustomerActions.getCustomerSuccess),
            catchError(err =>
              of(CustomerActions.getCustomerFailed(id, err.message)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

create an array of actions you want to do, then call `mergeMap` on it with `from`.

```js
// ....
mergeMap(([data]) => {
  const actions = data.map(item => Actions.someAction(item));
  // now actions is an array of actions we want to pass further.
  return from(actions);
})
```

then every item of the actions will be processed through the store.